# Azure DevOps query error when using @CurrentInteration

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I want to write a query to list all stories in the current sprint in ADO.
There is an annotation called @CurrentInteration , but it is throwing the error

"Expecting team value. The error is caused by @CurrentIteration." How do I handle this?

Comment: Can you check this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/query-by-date-or-current-iteration?view=azure-devops and particularly this part:

For the @CurrentIteration macro to work, the team must have selected an Iteration Path whose date range encompasses the current date. For details, see Define iteration paths (also referred to as sprints) and configure team iterations. Also, queries that contain this macro are only valid when run from the web portal.

See also Client restrictions on the use of the @@CurrentIteration macros later in this article.

Comment: How about the issue, is there anything to update?

Comment: I missed the option to select a team. Working now. It will be great if you can make teams field mandatory instead of throwing the error

Comment: I am glad to hear that your issue, would you mind share your solution as answer? As your suggestion, you could add your user voice for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions.

Answer (score 9):

> Azure DevOps query error when using @CurrentInteration

According to the document:

[Query by date or current iteration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/query-by-date-or-current-iteration?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts)

We could specify a team when using `@CurrentIteration` macro in queries, as follow:

[image]

Besides, At this time, the **Burnup** and **Burndown** widgets do not support `@CurrentIteration`. You could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

If above not help you, please share how did you use it in the query so that we could reproduce it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Leo, That is exactly what I was looking for. :)

Comment: Is it possible to provide this context while using the Excel extension? `Azure DevOps Office Integration 2019 (free)`